# How to loop through a fetched query in PHP using mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP class where I am initializing an array retrieved from database in the constructor:

```
class TableClass{
    public function __construct($con, $id){
        $this->con = $con;            
        $query = mysqli_query($this->con, "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id='$id'");
        $this->table_result= mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    }
}
```

I have different functions that I want to use the array without having to fetch again. I just want to loop through the results and make some calculations.

I tried the following syntax:

```
public function getNumberOfComments(){
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->table_result); $i++) {
          $comment= $this->table_result[$i]['comment'];                    
    }
}
```

I am getting an error:

> Illegal string offset "comment"

What is the correct syntax?

Comment: You're fetching only one row from the result set, so why are you using `for` loop? Simple `$comment= $this->table_result['comment'];` will do just fine.

Comment: first try to `print_r` the result `$this->table_result` to see what exactly has been fetched

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are fetching one row from the result set:

```
$this->table_result= mysqli_fetch_array($query);
```

Assuming that the `id` is the primary key, you will have 0 or 1 rows in your result set, so if a row is found, you can access the fields directly without using a loop:

```
$comment= $this->table_result['comment'];
```

Comment: Both of us posted at the exact(almost) same time. ;-)

Comment: I'm curious; since they're "construct"ing with `$this->con = $con;` and passing 2 arguments to the constructor, shouldn't `$id` also contain a property?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Could be, depends on the rest of the class. From what I can see even `$this->con` is unused / unneeded but perhaps in other methods...

Answer (score 0):

*Illegal string offset "comment"* is telling you that the value of `$this->table_result[$i]` is not an array, and therefore does not contain an element named `comment`.

The problem is possibly being caused by the code in the constructor failing to work properly; you don't have any error checking in there, so if it fails, it won't tell you about it.

Add some error checking in the constructor, find out why it's failing, and fix it.